# Covering space theory, category theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Requiring covering spaces of a well-behaved connected topological space $X$ to be connected, let $\mathcal{Cov}(X)$ be the category of covering spaces of $X$ and maps over $X$ and maps over $X$. Can anyone provide me with a quick way to see that if $G$ is the fundamental group of $X$, then $\mathscr{O}_G$ is equivalent, not isomorphic, to $\mathcal{Cov}(X)$? Thanks.

Comment: These notes by Jesper Møller should be helpful: http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5650

Comment: MSE is a good forum for this question.

Answer (score 1):

My book [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html) deals with covering **maps** of spaces by modelling them in terms of covering **morphisms** of groupoids, an approach which loosens the dependence on base points of the traditional approach. The account is developed from the1968, differently titled,  edition of that book, and is partially adopted in Peter May's "Concise..." text.

I learnt of this notion for groupoids from Philip Higgins in the 1960s, and it is developed also in his 1971 notes [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html), now downloadable, with applications to group theory.

I am not sure there is a quick way, but I feel the groupoid approach has advantages: given a topological space $X$ it asks for conditions for a covering morphism of groupoids $q: G \to \pi_1(X)$ to be realised up to isomorphism by a covering map $p: Y \to X$ of spaces, with $G \cong \pi_1(Y)$.

Using the fundamental groupoid also has advantages as shown in this paper: [Covering  groups of non-connected topological groups revisited](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/brown-mucuk-cov.pdf),  Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc, 115 (1994) 97-110. It brings out the relation of this question to crossed modules.